# ¿Cómo obtener el resultado de un Task?

Tags: c#, .net, backend, async, task

¿Cómo puedo imprimir el resultado de esta tarea por consola?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<PointOfUseEtis>> GetBomByLineCodeAsync()
{
    var linecode = GetLineCode();
    var Bom = (await _gtt.GetBomByLineCode(linecode).ConfigureAwait(false));
    return Bom;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Este es el Bom Actual");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: ¿Creo que así la pregunta se entiende mejor, está bien? Sino puedes revertir los cambios o modificar lo que creas que esté mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el resultado de un Task primero tienes que esperar a que su ejecución finalice. Para eso puedes usar la función Wait.

De este modo el hilo principal quedará bloqueado hasta que el Task termine.

Luego de eso, puedes verificar que el Task haya terminado correctamente mediante su propiedad [`IsCompletedSuccessfully`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompletedsuccessfully?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-task-iscompletedsuccessfully) y de ser así, obtener el resultado mediante su propiedad [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-task-1-result).

El código de la función `Main` se vería así:

```
var task = GetBomByLineCodeAsync();
task.Wait();

if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully){
    var result = task.Result;
    // Imprimir el resultado 
}
```

El resultado de la tarea es un `IEnumerable` así que probablemente quieras iterarlo para imprimir sus elementos.

Comment: Gracias me funciono tambien, tuve que hacer algunas modificaciones pero me funciono ahora el detalle es otro pero investigare eso muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes convertir el Main a `async` para poder usar el `await`

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<PointOfUseEtis>> GetBomByLineCodeAsync()
{
    var linecode = GetLineCode();
    var Bom = (await _gtt.GetBomByLineCode(linecode).ConfigureAwait(false));
    return Bom;
}

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = await GetBomByLineCodeAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono, tuve que hacer algunas modificaciones pero me funciono ahora el detalle es otro pero investigare eso muchas gracias.